# curl hitting the url but data not recieved by server

Tags: php, curl

Can anyone help me? I am tring to hit a website using `curl`.
My code is as follows:

```
$data = array(
    'utm_source'=>'Google',
    'utm_medium'=>'Google',
    'utm_campaign'=>'Sales',
    'utm_term'=>'united flights tickets'
);
$data = http_build_query($data, '', '&');
$proxies[] = 'user:password@71.6.46.151:443';
$proxies[] = 'user:password@14.102.19.206:61217';
$proxies[] = 'user:password@187.95.230.65:8080';
$url = 'https://www.example.com/index.php?'.$data;

$ch = curl_init();

if (isset($proxy)) { // If the $proxy variable is set, then
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy); // Set CURLOPT_PROXY with proxy in $proxy variable
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:5.0)    Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://www.google.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 500);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$results = curl_exec($ch);  // Execute a cURL request

if (curl_error($ch)) {
    $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
}

$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($error_msg);
print_r($info);
print_r($results);
```

It hits the website and also displayed in the Google Analytics account, but the only problem is that the refferer and source showing "direct" in Google Analytics.
If there is any other way to achive this, please tell me.

Comment: if you print out `$url` and it look's okay (containing data as `GET` Query-String), maybe the error is on server side?

Comment: I have already printed it and it looks ok. and its not the server problem i think because if i am using third party apps they doing the same thing on my same server please help me its very urgent...

Comment: Its third day of exploring in google but all in vain, no clue about my question, if anyone know please tell me if any other method to achieve this please post. its very urgent...